# How can i display products per each category stored in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

currently i created a schema for storing `products` using mongoose as below

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    manufacture: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'category'
    }
    
   
});

module.exports = { Product: mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema) };
```

and here another schema for storing `categories` that products are related to

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = { Category: mongoose.model('category', CategorySchema) };
```

each product is related to a category

the question is how can i display all products that are related to a specific category.

i tried `.find()` method but i can't use it correctly.

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.populate('category')](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population), after `.find()` in order to populate all the connected data.

```
products.find().populate('category').exec((err, product) => { })
```